# wordpress - Error 403 file javascript plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-403

I have problem in my wordpress plugin, website have plugin and in the plugin not load javascript, its say 403 forbidden when I go to link plugin [here](http://www.jalan2x.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=3.7.1). it's strange, because the file is exist. how can i solve this?

Comment: This can have several reasons, and many answers are available on the 'net. I would start by Googling  `error 403 wordpress` for pointers to possible solutions. Or even here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wordpress+403

Comment: hi @Pekka, many result use .htaccess but not work. I have try change permission 644 to 755 still not work. I dont understand this problem, so i ask here

Comment: How did you load the plugin, through Wordpress? Try downloading it nd uploading via FTP, could be a user issue (PHP sometimes runs under a different user that the FTP one)

Comment: no, I use existing plugin. Contactform plugin not load js too. all js/css/image in folder plugin (wp-content/plugin) not load or 403 forbiden (I check in firebug console error). I try remove, re-upload still not work. I try install in local (my cpu), the plugin is work correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your permision of directory and files to 775,

Answer (score 1):

Generally what this means is that the webserver does not have permission to access the file. For example, on OS X, there is a user called _www that needs permission.

Comment: Your best best is searching for your exact system. For example, 403 error apache2 ubuntu 12.04, or 403 error WAMP windows 7. Alternatively, edit the question to add more information, like the server OS, the webserver software, any steps to reproduce, etc.